# Using REST JSON objects in Angular 7 when you don't know the key names in advance

Tags: angular, rest, angular7

I've been butting my head up against a wall with this issue for the better part of the last day, so I'm throwing this out there with the hopes that some kind soul out there can shed some light for me.

So I have an Angular 7 application that makes a GET request against the AlphaVantage API. I have an interface which models the JSON response from the api and I am able to use the values returned. The problem is, the keys for this JSON response object are based on dates, so I cannot know ahead of time what the keys are going to be since they will change with time.

I've attempted to iterate through the object via looping to no avail.

Below is an example of what my interface looks like

```
 export interface SMA {
    'Meta Data': {
        '1: Symbol',
        '2: Indicator',
        '3: Last Refreshed',
        ...
    };
    'Technical Analysis: SMA' : {
        '2018-12-27': { 'SMA' },
        '2018-12-21': { 'SMA' },
        ...
    };
}
```

And here is an excerpt from the JSON response from alpha vantage

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1: Symbol": "MSFT",
        "2: Indicator": "Simple Moving Average (SMA)",
        "3: Last Refreshed": "2018-12-27",
        "4: Interval": "weekly",
        "5: Time Period": 10,
        "6: Series Type": "open",
        "7: Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Technical Analysis: SMA": {
        "2018-12-27": {
            "SMA": "106.7165"
        },
        "2018-12-21": {
            "SMA": "107.8395"
        },
        "2018-12-14": {
            "SMA": "108.4645"
        },
        ....
```

And here is how I am currently able to access the values. sma is an observable of SMA, so I am able to access the values like so

```
this.http.get<SMA>(this.uri)
    .subscribe( data => {
        symbol = data["Meta Data"]["1: Symbol"];
        value = data["Technical Analysis: SMA"]["2018-12-27"]["SMA"];
     });
```

So I am able to directly access these values directly by name, but is there a way for me to access these values in order without knowing the keys in advance? Ideally this application will be able to stay up to date with API responses, and theres no way I can do this by direct access via named parameters. Sorry if this is a complete noob question, I haven't been working in front end for very long and this is my first foray into working with RESTful apis.

Comment: Your interface definition is not valid TypeScript. Not sure why you're not posting the actual interface definition that compiles. But anyway, JavaScript, and thus TypeScript has Object.keys() and Object.entries() which allow getting... the keys and the entries of an object.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: Sorry for the invalid typescript, running off little sleep and typing mostly from memory. In any case, the observable data in this instance has no .keys() or .entries(). I've attempted to do .get<Object> but the compiler insists that Object has no such member functions.

Comment: **Read** my comment, and **read** the link I posted. The keys() and entries methods are static methods of Object. So you use them using Object.keys(data) or Object.entries(data). This is of course explained, with examples and everything, in the documentation I linked to. Why don't you read it? It's much, much more efficient to read documentation than to try random things until it ends up working.

Comment: Is your objective to create an interface that will be generic enough to fit the data model from the API, or to also create a way to pull specific data from the API without fully knowing its contents?

Comment: I am going to use the data returned to construct charts where the x-axis is the dates/keys (which will change over time) and the y-axis will be the actual value "SMA". Ultimately I'm going to construct charts for more indicators than just SMA, so my interface needs to be generic enough to accommodate the JSON results for all of the indicators if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't know the key names in advance you can use [Index signature](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html) to accept any property name.

```
interface Dic {
  [key: string]: {
    [prop: string]: string
  };
}

export interface SMA {
    'Meta Data' : {
        [prop: string]: string
    };
    'Technical Analysis: SMA': Dic;
}
```